# How to check 3rd is dash and first 2 are numbers?

Tags: java, string, validation

I have below string

```
11-abzw9rk
```

Here first 2 always going to be digit and then after -.

How I validate that first 2 always digit containing -.

Ofcourse can use `.contains()` but is there any better way to validate digit as well?

Comment: [The String class has other methods.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#method-summary)  You probably want to make use of the `length` and `charAt` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `^\\d{2}-`

`^` beginning of line

`\\d{2}` two digits

`-` dash

`.*` anything else

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2}-.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("11-abzw9rk");
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
if(matchFound) {
  System.out.println("Match found");
} else {
  System.out.println("Match not found");
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use a regular expression for this.  And it’s probably best if someone new to programming doesn’t try using regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple version that uses `String.charAt()` and `Character.isDigit()`

```java
String str = "11-abzw9rk";

//How to check 3rd is dash
if(str.charAt(2) == '-') {
    System.out.println("Yes, 3rd character is dash");
}

//and first 2 are numbers?
if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(1))) {
    System.out.println("Yes, first two are digits");
}
```

Comment: In one go: `"11-abzw9rk".matches("[0-9]{2}-.*")`.

Answer (score 1):

We can check all conditions in one if statement using `charAt` function of strings.
For example s is your string then the condition will be as follows :

```
  if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(1)) && s.charAt(2)=='-'){
    System.out.println("Match found");}
else{
    System.out.println("String doesn't match");
}
```

Comment: While this works, regex is easier and cleaner and is nice to learn (and with a little patience and reading is not very hard to understand)

Comment: And if he wanted to check first 15 characters what would you do?

Comment: then we must use regex but it is a bit advanced topic tho

Answer (score 0):

```
class Stringcheck{  
     public static void main(String[] args)  {  
         Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
         System.out.print("Enter the string: ");  
         String str= sc.nextLine();               
         if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(1)) && 
         (str.charAt(2)=='-'){
              System.out.println("Match found");
          }
         else{
              System.out.println("String doesn't match");
          }          
     }  
}
```